# my UITableView is empty the first time i build and run my app

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, datasource

I'm building an app that starts off with a `UITableView` however the first time I build and run my app on my phone the `UITableView` shows up empty. If I stop the run then re-build and run it again all the data shows up. Also If the app is already on my phone it builds and runs fine. It's just the first initial build and run when it "installs" the app on my phone that leaves the `UITableView` empty. I'm curious if this is going to cause any problems with apple when they review my app? And is there anything that I am doing wrong to make this happen?

note: the `UITableView` is being populated from a plist which is being moved to the documents directory. My original thought was that the `UITableView` is trying to populate the list before the plist has successfully been moved to the documents directory. So I tried to call `[self.tableView reloadData];` at the end of `viewDidLoad` method but I got the same result.

```
@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded
{
    //TESTING FOR EXISTENCE
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *searchPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [searchPaths lastObject];
    NSString *writeableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ScotchList.plist"];

    BOOL dbexists = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writeableDBPath];
    if (!dbexists) {
        // The writeable database does not exist, so copy the default to the appropriate location.
        NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ScotchList.plist"];

        NSError *error;
        BOOL success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:writeableDBPath error:&error];
        if (!success) {
            NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writeable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        MasterViewController *masterViewController = [[MasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MasterViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
        self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:masterViewController];

        self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    } else {
        MasterViewController *masterViewController = [[MasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MasterViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
        UINavigationController *masterNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:masterViewController];

        DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
        UINavigationController *detailNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detailViewController];

        masterViewController.detailViewController = detailViewController;

        self.splitViewController = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];
        self.splitViewController.delegate = detailViewController;
        self.splitViewController.viewControllers = @[masterNavigationController, detailNavigationController];

        self.window.rootViewController = self.splitViewController;
    }
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    [self createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded];
    [application setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque];
    return YES;
}
```

MasterViewController.m

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.sections = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    BOOL found;

    // Loop through the whiskys and create our keys
    for (NSMutableDictionary *whisky in self.drinks)
    {
        NSString *c = [[whisky objectForKey:NAME_KEY] substringToIndex:1];

        found = NO;

        for (NSString *str in [self.sections allKeys])
        {
            if ([str isEqualToString:c])
            {
                found = YES;
            }
        }

        if (!found)
        {
            [self.sections setValue:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] forKey:c];
        }
    }
    // Loop again and sort the whiskys into their respective keys
    for (NSMutableDictionary *whisky in self.drinks)
    {
        [[self.sections objectForKey:[[whisky objectForKey:NAME_KEY] substringToIndex:1]] addObject:whisky];
    }
    // Sort each section array
    for (NSString *key in [self.sections allKeys])
    {
        [[self.sections objectForKey:key] sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:NAME_KEY ascending:YES]]];
    }
        [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.582d0e
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0x015/255.0 green:0x04/255.0 blue:0x04/255.0 alpha:1];
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cellBackground.png"]];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0x3e/255.0 green:0x3e/255.0 blue:0x3e/255.0 alpha:1];
    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(insertNewObject:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0x015/255.0 green:0x04/255.0 blue:0x04/255.0 alpha:1];

    UIImage *titleImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"whiskeyTitle.png"];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:titleImage];

    NSArray *searchPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [searchPaths lastObject];
    NSString *writeableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ScotchList.plist"];

    NSMutableArray *tmpArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:writeableDBPath];

    self.drinks = tmpArray;
    deletedDrink = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(applicationDidEnterBackground:) 
                                                 name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
                                               object:nil];

    //Register for application exiting information so we can save data
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(applicationWillTerminate:) name:UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification object:nil];

    bookCover = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
    bookCover.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"];
    openBookButton = [[UIButton alloc]init];
    [openBookButton addTarget:self action:@selector(goToPage:flipUp:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    bookCover.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
    openBookButton.frame = bookCover.frame;

    [self.navigationController.view addSubview:bookCover];
    [self.navigationController.view addSubview:openBookButton];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

**OK UPDATE**

I have `NSLog()`'d my array that pulls from the plist in the `viewDidLoad` when the app is initially built and ran (installed) on the phone it logs null. If I stop and re-build and run it returns the information from the plist (not null).

Comment: I'm guessing that as the plist is being created on the first load, the plist is either not created by the time your datasource has received all of it's data. Post your code and people will be able to try and spot the problem there.

Comment: You are almost certainly going to get in trouble with Apple if they start your app for the first time, and the table view comes up empty. You need to look at what you are doing for the first time that you are not doing in subsequent invocations, and see if you are doing it in the right place. For example, moving the plist should probably be done in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`.

Comment: Post your code, else we can only guess what your code does,

Comment: Just posted my code.. MasterViewController is the view that has the `UITableView`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**GOT IT.** Basically I have a method in my `appDelegate.m` (`createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded`) that checks for a database (in my case a plist) inside my documents directory. If there is already an existing plist it will not overwrite it. If there isn't a plist then it moves the plist that I have shipped with the app to the documents directory. then inside of `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method I called `[self createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded];` which seems like it should be all good. However inside of the `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method there is the if statement to check the `currentDevice userInterfaceIdiom` I was calling `[self createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded];` after the if and the else that checks the interfaceIdiom. I simply just moved up into the if statement where the `userInterfaceIdiom` is the iPhone.

Below I have commented where the issue was and where I moved it to solve it.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        MasterViewController *masterViewController = [[MasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MasterViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
        self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:masterViewController];

        self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;

        //THIS WAS THE SOLUTION RIGHT BELOW.
        [self createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded];
    } else {
        MasterViewController *masterViewController = [[MasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MasterViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
        UINavigationController *masterNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:masterViewController];

        DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
        UINavigationController *detailNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detailViewController];

        masterViewController.detailViewController = detailViewController;

        self.splitViewController = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];
        self.splitViewController.delegate = detailViewController;
        self.splitViewController.viewControllers = @[masterNavigationController, detailNavigationController];

        self.window.rootViewController = self.splitViewController;
    }
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    //THIS IS WHERE [self createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded]; WAS ORIGINALLY WHICH WAS CAUSING THE PROBLEM
    [application setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the plist file is loaded and accessible on first load. Try something like this:

```
NSFileManager *filemgr;

filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: @"/CacheDirectory/DocumentDirectory/TempDirectory/myfile.txt" ] == YES)
        NSLog (@"File exists");
else
        NSLog (@"File not found");
```

Just to make sure. If it exist, try logging the data from it to see if it is fully populated before starting for the first time or if the app opens the file before it is fully on phone. When starting in simulator, apps start as soon as they are possible and there can be a switch of thread or something that cause the writing of the file to not fully complete before your app opens a stream from it... If it is what I think, it should not cause problem when installed on a user iPhone, as the app doesn't start as soon as it is installed.

Anyway, anyone who has an iPhone and use the facebook app is used to have nothing appear sometimes when they open an app and they will restart it... ;-)

Comment: "/tmp/" isn't a sandbox environment enabled filepath on iOS. I suggest that you use, in your example, the CacheDirectory/DocumentDirectory/TempDirectory.

Comment: good catch, but it was a generic example as to what general sintax might look... corrected!

Comment: Haha, those are examples of places where you could check to see where the file exists, not one directory path! Search google in regards to accessing the Documents Directory on iOS.